# Threading for sending continuous values to server

Tags: java, android

I am using this [tutorial](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html) . I have added the following code to send my value to server continuously but its not working  . Thanks

```
 public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    protected static Boolean c = true;
    ServicesDemo sd = new ServicesDemo();

    private Timer timer = new Timer();



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        startservice();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
         c=true;

                }




private void startservice() {

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {

         try {


             String data = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
             data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");


             //Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Latitude is = "+la+"Longitude is = "+longi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             URL url = new URL("http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat="+(int) (Math.random() * 45)+"&longi="+(int) (Math.random() * 45)+"&personid="+2+"&status="+3+"&name="+5+"");

             //URL url = new URL("http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat="+241+"&longi="+654+"");

                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    wr.write(data);
                    wr.flush();
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
                                        String line = null;
                                        String response = "";
                                        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                                           response += line;

                                        }

                                        wr.close();
                                        rd.close();



                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                //e.printStackTrace();
                            }


    }

    }, 0, 5000);

    ; }}
```

when i click on start button the logcat appears with the following errors

```
05-24 21:18:56.347: DEBUG/dalvikvm(5070): GC freed 8615 objects / 520600 bytes in 87ms
05-24 21:18:56.487: DEBUG/dalvikvm(491): GC freed 267 objects / 13280 bytes in 107ms
05-24 21:18:56.927: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=10&longi=34&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:18:56.927: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:18:56.927: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:18:56.937: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:18:57.597: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=39&longi=16&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:18:57.597: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:18:57.597: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:18:57.597: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:18:58.557: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=3&longi=18&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:18:58.557: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:18:58.557: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:18:58.557: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:18:59.577: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=15&longi=38&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:18:59.587: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:18:59.587: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:18:59.587: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:00.567: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=8&longi=17&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:00.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:00.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:00.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:01.577: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=40&longi=36&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:01.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:01.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:01.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:02.567: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=32&longi=4&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:02.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:02.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:02.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:03.677: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=18&longi=36&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:03.687: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:03.687: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:03.687: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:04.827: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=18&longi=4&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:04.827: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:04.837: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:04.837: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:05.287: DEBUG/dalvikvm(475): GC freed 101 objects / 5376 bytes in 159ms
05-24 21:19:05.597: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=44&longi=44&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:05.597: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:05.597: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:05.597: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:06.567: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=23&longi=44&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:06.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:06.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:06.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:07.577: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=2&longi=16&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:07.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:07.587: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:07.587: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:08.567: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=1&longi=3&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:08.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:08.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:08.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:09.577: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=5&longi=31&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:09.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:09.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:09.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:10.567: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=39&longi=10&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:10.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:10.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:10.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:11.567: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=37&longi=23&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:11.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:11.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:11.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:12.407: DEBUG/dalvikvm(5070): GC freed 8568 objects / 514384 bytes in 91ms
05-24 21:19:12.667: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=36&longi=29&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:12.667: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:12.667: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:12.667: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:13.567: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=23&longi=6&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:13.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:13.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:13.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:14.637: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=37&longi=31&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:14.637: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:14.637: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:14.637: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:15.577: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=7&longi=19&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:15.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:15.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:15.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:16.567: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=10&longi=2&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:16.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:16.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:16.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:17.557: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=39&longi=4&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:17.557: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:17.557: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:17.557: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:18.557: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=2&longi=15&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:18.557: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:18.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:18.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:19.577: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=22&longi=33&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:19.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:19.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:19.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:20.557: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=22&longi=37&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:20.557: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:20.557: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:20.557: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:21.657: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=3&longi=8&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:21.657: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:21.657: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:21.657: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:22.577: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=0&longi=13&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:22.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:22.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:22.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:23.567: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=4&longi=22&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:23.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:23.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:23.577: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:24.587: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=34&longi=12&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:24.587: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:24.587: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:24.587: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:25.597: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=28&longi=18&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:25.597: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:25.597: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:25.597: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:26.557: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=7&longi=2&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:26.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:26.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:26.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:27.567: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=6&longi=12&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:27.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:27.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:27.567: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:28.777: DEBUG/dalvikvm(5070): GC freed 8824 objects / 524672 bytes in 90ms
05-24 21:19:28.787: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=38&longi=33&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:28.797: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:28.797: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:28.797: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:29.717: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=39&longi=30&personid=2&status=3&name=5
05-24 21:19:29.717: WARN/System.err(5070):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
05-24 21:19:29.717: WARN/System.err(5070):     at com.example.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:82)
05-24 21:19:29.717: WARN/System.err(5070):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)
05-24 21:19:30.577: WARN/System.err(5070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=4&longi=4&personid=2&status=3&name=5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not good to start a Service with infinite loop with sleep there to schedule a recurring task. As the service (by default) is started on UI-thread this behaviour can lead to poor UI responsiveness. It is better to consider one the following scenarios:

1. You can try to use [Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29).
2. You can use a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) or [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)
3. You can create your own [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) with [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) to implement an infinite Thread with message queue, bind [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to it and then uset it to [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

IMO the second one is most preferable.

Comment: u mean to say like this http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/34861.aspx

Comment: please see the updated code . i have tried to use timer.scheduleAtFixedRate but now its not working

Comment: You are getting execption wile requesting an URL. It is not related to scheduling a recurring task. I've tryed to request your URL and got 500 error. The problem is at server side, as said by @Ben Williams

Comment: Thanks for your idea of  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate. Now how i can stop the service because it not getting stop on the stop button and i would like to know about this }, 1, 1000); how much time it is actually

Comment: Thanks its done all i need to add private void stopservice() {

  if (timer != null){

  timer.cancel();

  }

  }

Answer (score 1):

From your code, you are invoking the write only once hence only one request will be made. And even if you are doing one network operation in the service it is advisable to use a thread. The onStart method runs on the main thread and if the network operation takes long, an Application Not Responding (ANR) error will be thrown.

Take a look at [this blog](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-1-ui.html) for threading concepts.

Comment: Interesting tutorials ! other than this do i need to make data storage class for this , i mean getter and setters to make this working

Comment: Its upto you. It seems specific to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @advantej i have updated the code and tried to put the threading but still it only send for the first time so i was wondering to add something to get it work

Comment: Even in your thread, you are making only one request. What do mean by "it only send for first time" ? Can you explain what are you expecting to happen ? provide an example.

Comment: @advantej as in the url i am using this lat="+(int) (Math.random() * 45). so i want it should send continuously  random no to server as long as stop button is press. For the first time it send for example 5 then it stops when i again click the start button it send for eg 13 . so what i want the button should be pressed  once and this should start trigging random no untill the stop button is pressed

Comment: Can you try moving the url.openConnection() call outside the loop ?

Comment: @advantej please see the updated code .As many comments showed that i am going the in the wrong direction so i tried to used  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate but now its not sending value even for the first time

Comment: Is it throwing any exception ? I see that the e.printStackTrace is commented out. Check it.

Comment: @advantej oh yes . After removing this  when i am pressing start button logcat comes up with errors which i have now added in the question

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an Android Problem. The url is not accepting the data. Check the server side. Try posting data from browser by making GET requests (http://mediasense4.appspot.com/add.jsp?lat=10&longi=34&personid=2&status=3&name=5) -> This should be able to go through. If yes, you are all set !

Comment: @advantej thanks alot . Its is sometime Google app engine give some sort of strange errors . Its done . Now all i want to know how to stop my services because its not stoping when i am clicking on stop button and and i would like to know about this }, 1, 1000); how much time it is actually

Comment: @advantej Thanks its done . All i need to add this method private void stopservice() {

  if (timer != null){

  timer.cancel();

  }

  }

Answer (score 1):

The URL you're calling returns 500 Server Error when I call it by hand.  It seems like your problem could be at the server end?

Comment: yes a few sec b4 on the advantej advise i have also noticed this . and can u see the rest of the code is that ok for what i need